# Mathematica: set default value for argument to nonconstant?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, default-value

Can I set the default value for a function argument to be something 
that's not constant? Example:

```
tod := Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 86400] 
f[x_:tod] := x
```

In the above, 'tod' changes every time I evaluate it, but "f[]" does 
not. "?f" yields:

```
f[x_:42054.435657`11.376386798562935] := x
```

showing the default value was hardcoded when I created the function.

Is there a workaround here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to work if the function holds its arguments:

```
tod := Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 86400]
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[x_: tod] := x
```

In[23]:= f[]

Out[23]= 47628.994048

In[24]:= f[]

Out[24]= 47629.048193

Or you can use a construction like the following instead of a default value:

```
g[] := g[Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 86400]]
g[x_] := x
```

In[27]:= g[]

Out[27]= 47706.496195

In[28]:= g[]

Out[28]= 47707.842012

Comment: @Brett: it looks like your solution can be modified to remove the necessity of Hold attributes. All that matters is that system does not know what tod is when f is defined. So, we can either define tod after f, or use Block[{tod}, f[x_: tod] := x]

Comment: Thanks! The HoldAll was exactly what I needed. I actually had considered your 2nd approach, but was hoping for a solution that didn't involve modifying the original function.

Comment: Leonid, you're right -- reversing those two statements does what I want. However, I'm pretty sure that's a bug. Since both statements are ":=" (and not "="), their order of assignment shouldn't matter.

Comment: @barrycarter: Barry, this is not a bug. The situation is a bit more subtle. Consider the following defs: ClearAll[f, g,h]; g[x_] := x^2; f[h[g[y_]]] := y^3; Now check for f, and you'd be surprised:  f[h[y_^2]]:=y^3. What happens is that <g> evaluated during assignment, and this is in accordance with standard evaluation process (since h does not hold arguments). Now, in our case, you have f[Optional[Pattern[x, Blank[]], tod]], so the role of <h> is played by Optional. But if <tod> is not yet defined, it gets into a global definition as a symbol, and that's all that matters here.

Comment: @barrycarter: Forgot to mention another subtle point: the above behavior may still look strange, if we don't know the policy of SetDelayed, which is, in assignment like f[g[x, y]] := rhs, f and x and y are evaluated, while g[x,y] is not. This is a sensible thing in many cases, like i = 1; q[i] = 2; (i evaluates here), but in the above case it bites us. This is a design decision, could not be derived from Mathematica "first principles of evaluation". Had SetDelayed not evaluate deeper sub-parts, and we'd have no problem at all for this particular case (but maybe worse problems for other cases)

Comment: I realized later that "lazy evaluation" only applies to the RHS when you're using ":=". Mathematica doesn't specify how/when parameters are evaluated. It looks like immediate evaulation (same as "="), but, as you note, there may be something deeper going on here. Would this be "hold all but first"?

Comment: Actually, SetDelayed is HoldAll. But Hold attributes only specify what happens to arguments *before* they are passed to the function - are they evaluated or not. What happens to them then depends totally on the function in question. SetDelayed evaluates its l.h.s., but in a very special way, like I described before. I wish this point was better documented, so people wouldn't assume (as I also did for a long time) that SetDelayed does not evaluate its l.h.s.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, Set does it in the same way as SetDelayed (I mean, evaluation of the l.h.s)

Comment: @Leonid: Reordering the definition will work, as long as the code is only evaluated once, and so is more fragile than I'd prefer to use.  Of course I use Workbench a lot, which reloads the code whenever I save changes, so I'm a little sensitive to that sort of thing.  In cases where code does need to be in a specific order I use ClearAll to start from a clean state.

Comment: @Brett: I see. I have similar preferences. OTOH, Block trick should work regardless of the order of definitions. Both my suggestions are hacks, IMO. I never have such problems in my practice, since I try to avoid these sort of constructs (like non-constant defaults) from the start. But for the interactive session, this can be ok, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this:

```
f[] := f[Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 86400]]
f[x_] := x
```

Or equivalently, this:

```
f[x_:Null] := With[{x0 = If[x===Null, Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 86400], x]},
  x0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like HoldPattern for this purpose:

```
f[HoldPattern[x_ : Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 86400]]] := x
In[187]:= f[1]

Out[187]= 1

In[188]:= f[]

Out[188]= 57385.091442

In[189]:= f[]

Out[189]= 57385.972670
```