# Specifics of usage and internal work of *Set* functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I just noticed one undocumented feature of internal work of `*Set*` functions in *Mathematica*.

Consider:

```
In[1]:= a := (Print["!"]; a =.; 5);
a[b] = 2;
DownValues[a]

During evaluation of In[1]:= !

Out[3]= {HoldPattern[a[b]] :> 2}
```

but

```
In[4]:= a := (Print["!"]; a =.; 5);
a[1] = 2;
DownValues[a]

During evaluation of In[4]:= !

During evaluation of In[4]:= Set::write: Tag Integer in 5[1] is Protected. >>

Out[6]= {HoldPattern[a[b]] :> 2}
```

What is the reason for this difference? Why `a` is evaluated although `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst`? For which purposes such behavior is useful?

And note also this case:

```
In[7]:= a := (Print["!"]; a =.; 5)
a[b] ^= 2
UpValues[b]
a[b]

During evaluation of In[7]:= !

Out[8]= 2

Out[9]= {HoldPattern[5[b]] :> 2}

Out[10]= 2
```

As you see, we get the working definition for `5[b]` avoiding  `Protected` attribute of the tag `Integer` which causes error in usual cases:

```
In[13]:= 5[b] = 1

During evaluation of In[13]:= Set::write: Tag Integer in 5[b] is Protected. >>

Out[13]= 1
```

The other way to avoid this error is to use `TagSet*`:

```
In[15]:= b /: 5[b] = 1
UpValues[b]

Out[15]= 1

Out[16]= {HoldPattern[5[b]] :> 1}
```

Why are these features?

---

Regarding my question why we can write `a := (a =.; 5); a[b] = 2` while cannot `a := (a =.; 5); a[1] = 2`. In really in *Mathematica* 5 we cannot write `a := (a =.; 5); a[b] = 2` too:

```
In[1]:=
a:=(a=.;5);a[b]=2
From In[1]:= Set::write: Tag Integer in 5[b] is Protected. More...
Out[1]=
2
```

(The above is copied from *Mathematica* 5.2)

We can see what happens internally in new versions of *Mathematica* when we evaluate `a := (a =.; 5); a[b] = 2`:

```
In[1]:= a:=(a=.;5);
Trace[a[b]=2,TraceOriginal->True]
Out[2]= {a[b]=2,{Set},{2},a[b]=2,{With[{JLink`Private`obj$=a},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[JLink`CallJava`Private`setField[JLink`Private`obj$[b],2]]],Head[JLink`Private`obj$]===Symbol&&StringMatchQ[Context[JLink`Private`obj$],JLink`Objects`*]]],{With},With[{JLink`Private`obj$=a},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[JLink`CallJava`Private`setField[JLink`Private`obj$[b],2]]],Head[JLink`Private`obj$]===Symbol&&StringMatchQ[Context[JLink`Private`obj$],JLink`Objects`*]]],{a,a=.;5,{CompoundExpression},a=.;5,{a=.,{Unset},a=.,Null},{5},5},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[JLink`CallJava`Private`setField[5[b],2]]],Head[5]===Symbol&&StringMatchQ[Context[5],JLink`Objects`*]],{RuleCondition},{Head[5]===Symbol&&StringMatchQ[Context[5],JLink`Objects`*],{And},Head[5]===Symbol&&StringMatchQ[Context[5],JLink`Objects`*],{Head[5]===Symbol,{SameQ},{Head[5],{Head},{5},Head[5],Integer},{Symbol},Integer===Symbol,False},False},RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[JLink`CallJava`Private`setField[5[b],2]]],False],Fail},a[b]=2,{a[b],{a},{b},a[b]},2}
```

I was very surprised to see calls to Java in such a pure language-related operation as assigning a value to a variable. Is it reasonable to use Java for such operations at all?

---

Todd Gayley (Wolfram Research) [has explained](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/b32c39040482aeac) this behavior:

> At the start, let me point out that in
>   Mathematica 8, J/Link no longer
>   overloads Set. An internal kernel
>   mechanism was created that, among
>   other things, allows J/Link to avoid
>   the need for special, er, "tricks"
>   with Set.
>
> J/Link has overloaded Set from the
>   very beginning, almost twelve years
>   ago. This allows it support this
>   syntax for assigning a value to a Java
>   field:
>
> ```
>  javaObject@field = value
> ```
>
> The overloaded definition of Set
>   causes a slowdown in assignments of
>   the form
>
> ```
>  _Symbol[_Symbol] = value
> ```
>
> Of course, assignment is a fast
>   operation, so the slowdown is small in
>   real terms. Only highly specialized
>   types of programs are likely to be
>   significantly affected.
>
> The Set overload does *not* cause a
>   call to Java on assignments that do
>   not involve Java objects (this would
>   be very costly). This can be verified
>   with a simple use of TracePrint on
>   your a[b]=c.
>
> It does, as you note, make a slight
>   change in the behavior of assignments
>   that match _Symbol[_Symbol] = value.
>   Specifically, in f[_Symbol] = value, f
>   gets evaluated twice. This can cause
>   problems for code with the following
>   (highly unusual) form:
>
> ```
>  f := SomeProgramWithSideEffects[]
>  f[x] = 42
> ```
>
> I cannot recall ever seeing "real"
>   code like this, or seeing a problem
>   reported by a user.
>
> This is all moot now in 8.0.

Comment: Before I go, after reading your last update, all I can say is: what the devil is that? lol

Comment: I can not reproduce this behavior in v8. BOth evaluations generate messages

Comment: @Sasha I use v.7.01. BTW, what you get by evaluating `DownValues[Set]`? I get ``{HoldPattern[
   JLink`Private`sym_Symbol[JLink`Private`arg_Symbol] = 
    JLink`Private`val_] :> 
  With[{JLink`Private`obj = JLink`Private`sym}, 
   JLink`CallJava`Private`setField[
     JLink`Private`obj[JLink`Private`arg], JLink`Private`val] /; 
    Head[JLink`Private`obj] === Symbol && 
     StringMatchQ[Context[JLink`Private`obj], "JLink`Objects`*"]]}``.

Comment: `DownValues[Set]` in Mma 8.0.1 returns an empty list.  The definition you show implements the JLink syntax for object field assignment, e.g. `obj@field = value`.  In Mma 8, either JLink now does this another way, or the rule has been moved behind the read-protected curtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the case of `UpSet` first, this is expected behavior.  One can write:

```
 5[b] ^= 1
```

The assignment is made to `b` not the Integer `5`.

Regarding `Set` and `SetDelayed`, while these have Hold attributes, they still internally evaluate expressions.  This allows things such as:

```
p = n : (_List | _Integer | All);

f[p] := g[n]
```

Test:

```
f[25]
f[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}]
f[All]
```

```
   g[25]
```

```
   g[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}]
```

```
   g[All]
```

One can see that heads area also evaluated.  This is useful at least for `UpSet`:

```
p2 = head : (ff | gg);
p2[x] ^:= Print["Echo ", head];

ff[x]
gg[x]
```

> Echo ff
>
> Echo gg

It is easy to see that it happens also with `Set`, but less clear to me how this would be useful:

```
j = k;
j[5] = 3;
DownValues[k]

(* Out=  {HoldPattern[k[5]] :> 3}  *)
```

---

My analysis of the first part of your question was wrong.  I cannot at the moment see why `a[b] = 2` is accepted and `a[1] = 2` is not.  Perhaps at some stage of assignment the second one appears as `5[1] = 2` and a pattern check sets off an error because there are no Symbols on the LHS.

Comment: In your example only argument of the function is evaluated while the question is about evaluation of the symbol of the function (`Head` of l.h.s).

Comment: @Alexey, see the edit in the middle of the post.  Also, there was an error I corrected just now, so please make sure you refresh the page.

Comment: But why one may not write `a := (a =.; 5); a[1] = 2` while one may write `a := (a =.; 5); a[b] = 2`?

Comment: @Alexey, I thought for a few minutes I understood, but I was wrong.  I do not know.  My only idea is in the last sentence of my last edit.

Comment: BTW, one cannot Set `5[b]` just because the tag `Integer` is `Protected`. We can `Unprotect` it and then set freely: `Unprotect[Integer]; 5[b] = 1; 5[b]`.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Aren't you in PST? Shouldn't you be sleeping?

Comment: @yoda, yes, but you've seen the graph. 8-s

Comment: @Mr. The graph's a lie! Those are just bots editing/retagging/flagging... no wonder you have the strunk & white and depty badges. your flag weight is 645! o_O

Comment: @yoda don't I wish it; if I could write bots that good, I'd be rich.

Comment: @Alexey  You may want to look at my comments to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661583/mathematica-set-default-value-for-argument-to-nonconstant/4661633#4661633, they are complementary to @Mr.Wizard's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The behavour you show appears to be a bug in 7.0.1 (and possibly earlier) that was fixed in Mathematica 8.  In Mathematica 8, both of your original `a[b] = 2` and `a[1] = 2` examples give the `Set::write ... is protected` error.

The problem appears to stem from the JLink-related down-value of `Set` that you identified.  That rule implements the JLink syntax used to assign a value to the field of a Java object, e.g. `object@field = value`.

`Set` in Mathematica 8 does not have that definition.  We can forcibly re-add a similar definition, thus:

```
Unprotect[Set]
HoldPattern[sym_Symbol[arg_Symbol]=val_] :=
  With[{obj=sym}
  , setField[obj[arg], val] /; Head[obj] === Symbol && StringMatchQ[Context[obj],"Something`*"]
  ]
```

After installing this definition in Mathematica 8, it now exhibits the same inconsistent behaviour as in Mathematica 7.

I presume that JLink object field assignment is now accomplished through some other means.  The problematic rule looks like it potentially adds costly `Head` and `StringMatchQ` tests to every evaluation of the form `a[b] = ...`.  Good riddance?

Comment: @Mr.W The definition could easily be removed (using `Unset`), but it would be hard to know what other functionality would be broken along with that removal.  Mma uses JLink internally for various purposes, so there could be subtle and far-reaching consequences (not unlike those that appear to have bitten WRI in this particular case ;)