# Question on Definition and values of symbols

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

`Definition` "knows" the way how a value for a symbol was defined: using `Set` or `SetDelayed`. But how? As I understand, after a value for a symbol was assigned there is no any difference for the evaluator how it was assigned: by using `Set` or `SetDelayed`. It can be illustrated by the function `OwnValues` which always returns definitions with the `Head` `RuleDelayed`. How `Definiton` obtains this information?

```
In[1]:= a=5;b:=5;
Definition[a]
Definition[b]
OwnValues[a]

Out[2]= a=5
Out[3]= b:=5
Out[4]= {HoldPattern[a]:>5}
```

Comment: Another good question Alexey.

Comment: There is one very important use case where it makes a real difference what was used in assignment - `Set` or `SetDelayed`: the `Part` assignment. Confront `tst = {1, 2, 3}; tst[[2]] = 5; tst` (works all right) with `tst1 := {1, 2, 3}; tst1[[2]] = 5` (gives assignment error, "no immediate value" for `tst1`). And of course, `OwnValues` for `tst` and `tst1` look the same, just as you observed. Given your observation on memory consumption, I'd guess that delayed definitions may use some intermediate internal variables, while immediate ones point straight to the memory where the data is stored.

Answer (score 7):

`OwnValues[a] = {HoldPattern[a] -> 3}; OwnValues[a]` gives `{HoldPattern[a] :> 3}` instead of `{HoldPattern[a] -> 3}` but `Definition[a]` shows what one can expect. Probably this definition is stored internally in the form of `Rule` but is converted to `RuleDelayed` by `OwnValues` for suppressing of evaluation of the r.h.s of the definition. This hypothesis contradicts my original understanding that there are no difference between values assigned by `Set` and `SetDelayed`. Probably such definitions are stored in different forms: `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` correspondingly but are equivalent from the evaluator's point of view.

It is interesting to see how `MemoryInUse[]` depends on the kind of definition.

In the following experiment I used the kernel of *Mathematica* 5.2 in interactive session without the FrontEnd. With the kernels of *Mathematica* 6 and 7 one will get different results. One reason for this is that [in these versions `Set` is overloaded by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846756/specifics-of-usage-and-internal-work-of-set-functions).

First of all I evaluate `$HistoryLength=0;` for having `DownValues` for `In` and `Out` variables not affecting my results. But it seems that even when `$HistoryLength` is set to 0 the value of `In[$Line]` for **current** input line is still stored and removed after entering new input. This is likely the reason why result of the first evaluation of `MemoryInUse[]` always differs from the second.

Here is what I have got:

> Mathematica 5.2 for Students: Microsoft Windows Version
>
> Copyright 1988-2005 Wolfram Research, Inc.
>
> -- Terminal graphics initialized --
>
> In[1]:= $HistoryLength=0;
>
> In[2]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[2]= 1986704
>
> In[3]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[3]= 1986760
>
> In[4]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[4]= 1986760
>
> In[5]:= a=2;
>
> In[6]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[6]= 1986848
>
> In[7]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[7]= 1986824
>
> In[8]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[8]= 1986824
>
> In[9]:= a:=2;
>
> In[10]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[10]= 1986976
>
> In[11]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[11]= 1986952
>
> In[12]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[12]= 1986952
>
> In[13]:= a=2;
>
> In[14]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[14]= 1986848
>
> In[15]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[15]= 1986824
>
> In[16]:= MemoryInUse[]
>
> Out[16]= 1986824

One can see that defining `a=2;` increases `MemoryInUse[]` by 1986824-1986760=64 bytes. Replacing it with the definition `a:=2;` increases `MemoryInUse[]` by 1986952-1986824=128 bytes. And replacing the latter definition with the former reverts `MemoryInUse[]` to 1986824 bytes. It means that delayed definitions require 128 bytes more than immediate definitions.

Of course this experiment does not prove my hypothesis.

Comment: +1 for your continued probing of the inner workings of Mathematica

Answer (score 4):

Complete definition for a symbol can be accessed via undocumented new-in-8 symbols `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` and `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``. Citing [Oleksandr Rasputinov](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/0hw5IkrdsTU/v2404uYo9GsJ):

"If anyone is curious,  `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` and `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` are  analogous to `Definition` and `FullDefinition` but capture the definition of a  symbol in such a way as it can be reproduced in another kernel. For  example, `` defs = Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[sym] `` returns a  `` Language`DefinitionList `` object. The syntax used to restore the definition  is highly irregular: `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = defs ``, where `defs`  is a `` Language`DefinitionList ``. Note that `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``  takes the `ExcludedContexts` option whereas `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` does not."

Answer (score 3):

`Information` calls `Definition`, and a Trace on `Definition` (or `FullDefinition`) shows nothing.  I must assume that this is a low level function that accesses data outside of the `*Values` tables.  Perhaps it keeps a copy of the original definition expressions as they were parsed at that time.

Comment: Not at the parsing time: `a = 1 + 1; Definition[a]` gives `a=2`. I suppose that in really `OwnValues` keep the information on the definitions but does not show it: if we evaluate `OwnValues[a] = {HoldPattern[a] -> 3}; Definition[a]` we get `a = 3`.

Comment: @Alexey on the first point, I did not mean "parse" I meant "evaluation" (my mistake).  On the second, good observation, and it contradicts what I supposed.  Also try: `OwnValues[a] = {HoldPattern[a] :> 3}; Definition[a]`  I need to think about this.

Comment: @Sjoerd @Mr. Did you see this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35591/a-series-solution-of-the-differential-equation-fracd2uxdx2-uxn-0

Comment: @belisarius Do you mean this specific question? I didn't even know that MO had a Mathematica tag.

Comment: @Sjoerd My intention was to alert you both on that :)

Comment: @belisarius I'll try to track that one as well then. Pity reputation starts at base zero again. No way to merge MO and SO rep?

Comment: @Sjoerd MO is not the same as math.stackexchange.  One intimidates me substantially more than the other.  Just sayin' :)

Comment: @Sjoerd I've 143 there without being done almost nothing, so I guess my accounts are merged