# Is it possible to delete "context`" from the list of loaded Contexts[]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

We can remove all symbols in a particular context by using `` Remove["context`*"] ``. But is it possible to remove `` "context`" `` itself from the system so that it will no longer be listed in [`Contexts[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Contexts.html)?

Comment: Will `CleanSlate` not do this?

Comment: I don't see how it can be done. If you are having problems with conflicting contexts then I would remove the context from the `$ContextPath` so that it doesn't causes me any more trouble.

Comment: @TomD Yes, as Bill Rowe has showed in [his MathGroup answer](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/de14f4aff3c6e780), ``AppendTo[$ContextPath, "context`"]; CleanSlate["context`"]`` will do this (if ``"context`"`` was not on the initial `$ContextPath` when `CleanSlate.m` was read in). But quick looking on `CleanSlate` description in the `CleanSlate.m` file reveals that it just purges ``"context`"`` **along with all of its subcontexts** for having this context to be removed automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell (a guess), a context is automatically removed from `Contexts[]` once it becomes empty (has no symbols). At least, this happens in my tests. Here is one:

```
In[1]:= 
BeginPackage["Test`"]
EndPackage[]

Out[1]= Test`

In[3]:= MemberQ[Contexts[],"Test`"]
Out[3]= False

In[4]:= Test`a
Out[4]= a

In[5]:= MemberQ[Contexts[],"Test`"]
Out[5]= True

In[6]:= Remove["Test`*"]
In[7]:= MemberQ[Contexts[],"Test`"]

Out[7]= False
```

This may also explain why calling `Contexts[]` takes a sizable fraction of a second - the system must check for every context whether or not it is empty. Anyways, the answer to your question seems simple - remove all symbols and the context will be removed from `Contexts[]`. This also works for contexts loaded by the system - you may try some (`XML'` for example), although needless to say this is not a good practice, to say the least.

Comment: This does not work for my as the package still remains in the `$ContextPath` so e.g. `Needs` will not reload it. Any idea why?

Comment: @ThomasFankhauser No idea. But I was discussing here something else.  Make a self-contained small example to illustrate your issue and ask on M.SE - this way you will have more eyes on your issue.