# How do Clear[] & ClearAll[] operate? Clear[] failing to clear out variables used by two different Manipulate[]s

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have two different Mathematica notebooks with similar, but different functions. Both work fine when they're the only notebook open.  One of them consistently fails when the other notebook is open, despite my (liberal) use of Clear[] to clear out the relevant variables.

Call this one, say, **GlobalManipulate**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Clear["Global`*"]
Definition[linear]
linear[x_] := a x;
quad[x_] := a x^2;
functionList := {linear, quad};
Manipulate[
  Plot[function[dummy], {dummy, -10, 10}], 
  {function, functionList}, {a, -10, 10},
  LocalizeVariables -> False, TrackedSymbols -> All
]
```

Call this one, say, **LocalManipulate**

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
Manipulate[
   {
      linear := a x; quad := a x^2; 
      linear, quad, function, 
      Plot[ReleaseHold@function, {x, -10, 10}]
   }, 
   {function, {HoldForm@linear, HoldForm@quad}}, 
   {a, -10, 10}, TrackedSymbols -> All
]
```

When run by itself, GlobalManipulate works as expected and I see the plot that updates as `a` is changed.  The definition of linear produces `Null`.

When LocalManipulate is open, running, GlobalManipulate no longer works. **even when it's rerun** It's plot appears for a second and then vanishes.

I've reproduced this using my local copy of Mathematica 8 and a remote copy of Mathematica 7.

The problem must involve the functions `linear[x_]` and `quad[x_]` since

**GlobalManipulatePrime**:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Clear["Global`*"]
Definition[linear]
linear1[x_] := a x;
quad1[x_] := a x^2;
functionList := {linear1, quad1};
Manipulate[
  Plot[function[dummy], {dummy, -10, 10}], 
  {function, functionList}, {a, -10, 10}, 
  LocalizeVariables -> False, TrackedSymbols -> All
]
```

works fine.

**Edited to add bold text to stress that I'm rerunning Global, and that I'm trying to figure out why functions persist despite my ClearAll[].**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from wrapping the functions in `Module` or `DynamicModule` and localizing the variables you could also place the notebooks in individual contexts using the `Evaluation ► Notebook's Default Context` menu.

You could also set the context using the function `Begin`. This should all be done before your functions are defined.

**Update**

I didn't read your question too well I think. As to the *cause* of ClearAll not working:

1. Because of the definition of linear in LocalManipulate using the
   localized variable a, the *symbol* linear gets defined as something like `` linear:=FE`a$$51 x ``
2. In GlobalManipulate you use both the *name* linear (in the function selection) and the *function* linear
3. Because of defining the symbol `linear` in `` FE`a$$51 x `` the line `functionList := {linear, quad};` in GlobalManipulate now actually means `` functionList := {FE`a$$51 x,FE`a$$53 x^2} `` which, out of the other `Manipulate` context, doesn't mean anything, so your plot disappears
4. Why then doesn't `ClearAll` remove this definition? This has to do with the properties of the dynamic variables buried in the Manipulate box visible in the LocalManipulate notebook. They keep on getting redefined there. Remove the output of the Manipulate and re-execute GlobalManipulate and you'll see it now works. Something similar is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579644/615464).

Comment: Very useful things to know. Thanks. But I'm still wondering why the ClearAll in Global doesn't allow it to work if it's run subsequent to Local.

Answer (score 5):

Inside your **LocalManipulate** you have the definitions 
`linear := a x; quad := a x^2`.
Since these are not declared in the controller part of the `Manipulate` command, they are not localized and thus overwrite the global variables and break your **GlobalManipulate**.

The simplest way to localize variables inside a `Manipulate` is to use add them in with the controller type `None`. Below I've modified your **LocalManipulate** code, so that the last line makes `linear` and `quad` local to that particular `Manipulate` (`DynamicModule`)

```
Manipulate[{linear := a x; quad := a x^2; linear, quad, function, 
  Plot[ReleaseHold@function, {x, -10, 10}]},
 {function, {HoldForm@linear, HoldForm@quad}}, {a, -10, 10}, 
 {linear, None}, {quad, None}, TrackedSymbols -> All]
```

Comment: I like the "ControllerType-> None" trick, and I'm sure it will be useful. But I'm still wondering why the ClearAll in Global doesn't allow it to work if it's run subsequent to Local.